# padding issue while decryption using AES256 with ECB mode in java

Tags: java, ios, aes, cryptoapi

Hi I have issue while decrypting a String which is encrypted in IOS environment using AES256 with ECB mode. I have to decrypt this encrypted string in java.

Let me share my code for decryption in java

```
public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
     byte[] key = "12345678911234567891123456789112".getBytes("UTF-8");

    try
    {   Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
        final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        final String decryptedString = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
        return decryptedString;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error while decrypting"+ e);

    }
    return null;
}
```

Encryption code at IOS platform

```
- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key:(NSString *)plaintext {

// 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise

char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)

bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

// fetch key data

[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



    NSLog(@" key ptr string %s",keyPtr);

NSData *dTextIn=[plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSUInteger dataLength = [dTextIn length];

//See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or

//equal to the input size plus the size of one block.

//That's why we need to add the size of one block here

size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;

void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;

CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128,kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,

                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,

                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,

                                          [dTextIn bytes], dataLength, /* input */

                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */

                                          &numBytesEncrypted);

if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {

//the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation

return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];

}





free(buffer); //free the buffer;

return nil;

}

   original string is "my name is nitish" // which is encoded in IOS Platform, padding PKCS7Padding and ECB Mode
Encrypted String1 in IOS platform is "p1sBWnbfE/5g3RdT7PHBFy6idtGJlpLBq5IqKV4wXKQ="
Encrypted string in java platform is "p1sBWnbfE/5g3RdT7PHBF8z1aSePf1f9hn6Z33GdrRI="
```

I don't know what is the error and why I can't decrypt the ios String in java platform but i can Decrypt encrypted string in Java platform. Please give some solution.

error is decryptingjavax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted

thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us the iOS code as well, it is very likely that you are using CBC mode with a zero valued IV instead. This would yield the same decryption for the first block, but random bytes for the next blocks.

Comment: I have update my IOS code. please see if there any conflicts for padding or mode.